# Are view.superview.layer and view.layer.superlayer the same?

Tags: ios

For a UIView view, is view.superview.layer always the same as view.layer.superlayer ?

In which case they are not the same?

Answer (score 0):

They should be the same.  There is always a way to do weird things, like swizzle the superlayer getter, or override the layer getter, or whatever, but if you're the one controlling all the UIViews, then you shouldn't have to worry about those strange cases.  You can always NSAssert() that it is the case if you're paranoid.